# UnicodeEncodeError when using os.listdir

Tags: python

- OS: Windows 7, 64-bit
- Python 3.1.3

When I try to do this

```
os.listdir("F:\\music")
```

I get this

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 643: illegal multibyte sequence
```

`os.listdir` works with other directories so the cause of the problem is obviously some strangely-encoded file or folder within `F:\music` itself. How do I find the source of this error?

Comment: does `os.listdir(r"F:\music")` work inside Idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnicodeEncodeError` indicates that you are trying to print the filenames. If it was `os.lisdir()` that had a problem you should see a `UnicodeDecodeError` (*Decode*, not *Encode*).

Because you use a Unicode pathname, `os.listdir()` returns readily decoded filenames; on Windows the filesystem uses UTF-16 to encode filenames and those are easily decoded in Python ([`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) tells Python what codec to use).

However, the Windows console uses a *different* encoding; in your case `gbk`, and that codec cannot display all the different characters that UTF-16 can encode.

You are looking for a `print()` statement here. You perhaps could use `print(filename.encode('gbk', errors='replace'))` to try and print the filenames instead; unprintable characters will be replaced by a question mark.

Alternatively, you could use a `b'F:\\music'` as the path and work with raw bytestrings instead of Unicode.

Comment: +1 for identifying it as [Windows console Unicode problem](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602). A nitpick: `os.listdir("..")` returns Unicode strings so it doesn't matter what encodings console and fs use as long as the characters are representable. `os.listdir` probably uses Unicode API on Windows so `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is not used and `UnicodeDecodeError` is unlikely.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: According to [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames) `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is used. I am having some trouble locating the source of the `nt` module though to confirm.

Comment: [the source says](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a6fa1b8767f/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2248) that on wide-character-capable OS [among Windows family] Unicode API is used (Python doesn't see bytes at all so nothing to decode in this case).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's the thing; that's the `posix` module; it is not used on Windows, where the `nt` module is used instead. Although seeing the Windows defs in there perhaps I am misunderstanding something in the `os.py` module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: aHA! So *that's* where `nt` is hiding! Cool, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: If you pass a unicode string to os.listdir, you'll get unicode strings back, which may be more useful/easy to convert into something that can be converted to an encoding that the Windows console can display.

Answer (score 1):

It's a windows console unicode problem, you can fix it by install the [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) library

```
$ pip install win-unicode-console
$ edit a.py

  import win_unicode_console

  win_unicode_console.enable()
  print('non-gbk-character Résumé or 欧•亨利 works')
```

I've tested in python 3.4 in Chinese Windows 8

Comment: note: you could avoid editing your script if you use `run` module (installed with `win-unicode-console`): `py -m run your_unmodified_script_that_prints_unicode.py` (make sure you've configured fonts in the console).

Comment: Or you can put `win_unicode_console.enable()` into your `sitecustomize` to fix this issue globally for your Python installation.

Comment: This is outdated as Python 3.6+ already has this fixed. So if you have 3.6+ this is not the problem.