# os.listdir is removing character accent

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.6

In windows file explorer, create a new txt file and name it `Ń.txt` (note the accent over the `N`).

Hold shift and right click the folder where you created `Ń.txt` and select open command window here (or alternatively open cmd.exe and cd into the directory where you created the file).

Run in python terminal:

```
print os.listdir(".")  #note that the file is displayed as "N.txt"
print map(os.path.exists,os.listdir(".")) #note the file doesn't exist???
```

I have tried many decodings but `os.listdir` is not returning the bytestring of the actual filename at all, so encoding/decoding the incorrect bytes is still the incorrect bytes.

Comment: Not a dupe, might contain relevant info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876810/unicodeencodeerror-when-using-os-listdir

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit the question to highlight the problem (it took me several readings to notice the accent).

Comment: What does `os.listdir(u".")` return (with the `u""`)?

Comment: os.listdir(u".") returns [u'\u0143.txt'] and 
print map(os.path.exists,os.listdir(u".")) works well

Comment: Pretty strange behaviour...

Comment: When I do this with Python 2.6.7 on Linux, ``os.listdir`` returns a string that does the right thing.  In my case ``'\xc3\x91'`` (different accent, wasn't able to type ´N).  ``os.path.exists`` verified that the filename was right and existed.  So can this mean it's a bug in the windows implementation of ``os.listdir``?

Comment: thanks guys! thats great :) it worked passing in the path as unicode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `u` before that:

```
>>> print os.listdir(u".")
[u'\u0143.txt']
>>> print map(os.path.exists,os.listdir(u"."))
[True]
```

[os.listdir(path)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> Changed in version 2.3: On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if **path** is a
>   **Unicode object**, the result will be a list of **Unicode objects**.
>   **Undecodable filenames** will still be returned as **string objects**.